# How to add 404 error page in ruby on rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-status-code-404

Can you help me in this. I want to add 404 error page to my website.
I tried many ways but nothing works for me.
Here is one of them.

ApplicationController

```
unless  ActionController::Base.consider_all_requests_local
  rescue_from Exception, :with => :render_404
end

private

  def render_404
    render :template => 'error_pages/404', :layout => false, :status => :not_found
  end
```

Then set up error_pages/404.html

Can anyone fix this?

Comment: Don't rescue `Exception`, it's evil. Rescue `StandardError` if you have to.

And BTW could you be a little bit more specific? What does it mean it 'didn't work'?

Comment: Thank you for this. Do you have any other way? I want when anyone type anything after the url that doesn't have in the route to bring 404 html page

Comment: Rails by default call 404.html from public folder, you can also define 404 to an custom controller by adding `match '404', to: 'custom_errors#not_found', via: :all` in routes.rb and `config.exceptions_app = routes ` in application.rb

Comment: Can you put this in the answer section but with more explanation please

Comment: Here is a video for the solution https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWGCiHDP-u4&t=144s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rescuing 404 (usually originating from `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`) from your controller will not always help, because there're also routing errors (`ActionController::RoutingError`)

To present exceptions to user rails calls `config.exceptions_app`, which defaults to `ActionDispatch::PublicExceptions.new(Rails.public_path)` and just renders `public/404.html` etc.

For most cases it's enough to place your error pages there, but if you absolutely must render something dynamic - you can override the exceptions app.

One common hack is to route exceptions back into your main routes via `config.exceptions_app = self.routes` and adding regular routes to handle them:

```
get '/404', to: 'errors#not_found'
get '/422', to: 'errors#unacceptable'
get '/500', to: 'errors#server_error'
```

But beware, that if there's already an exception - you may get an exception loop, so it's better to have separate error handling app/engine

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply wanting custom *static* error pages, you can change the HTML inside of public/404.html, public/422.html and public/500.html.